# Cannot Assign a Value to an Unbound Textbox Upon Opening a Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that performs slightly differently depending on where the user has arrived from - so to differentiate, I have an unbound textbox showing either 1 or 0. When opened from the form that requires a 1, this is the code I use:

```
Private Sub ProductDetailsButton_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_ProductDetailsButton_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "BrandProductIndividualDetails"

    stLinkCriteria = "[Ref]=" & Me![Ref]
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
    Forms!BrandProductIndividualDetails!OrderCount = 1

Exit_ProductDetailsButton_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_ProductDetailsButton_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " Error - " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_ProductDetailsButton_Click

End Sub
```

Any idea why I get a "2448 - Cannot Assign a Value to this Object" error?

Comment: me![ref] works fine! It's the line two below it that's the problem (the entire code works if I take that line out)

Comment: A guess: OrderCount is the name of both a bound field *and* a control on BrandProductIndividualDetails, and the control doesn't like its value set unless it has the focus.

Comment: Ignore all this - Chris was sort of right, I was trying to assign the value to the wrong control!

Problem solved.